# How do I ecourage my spouse, in Mandarin, to fly free in her job, and assure here we are supporting her and welcoming her home

Tags: meaning-in-context, mandarin, sentence-structure

My spouse just landed their dream job! They start next week and I am going to celebrate their first day.
Their dream is to be able to fly free, and high and to always be welcomed home in a warm and caring way. I want to express that, in addition to our unconditional support for them.

I have found several ways to congratulate them on a new job, including:
恭喜您获得这个工作
对你的新工作表示祝贺
祝您今后在工作岗位上大展鸿图！

But I really want to go beyond congratulating, in an authentic and meaningful way. Possibly referencing 瑤池金母, who represents "he protector/patron of "singing girls, dead women, novices, nuns, adepts and priestesses...women [who] stood outside the roles prescribed for women in the traditional Chinese family"" according to wikipedia.

Here is the best I've come up with, but I don't think it is very good. Would you please help me phrase my intentions?

加油！自由飞翔！
我们在这里为您服务，始终支持您并欢迎您回家！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
恭喜你找到梦寐以求的工作。我真为你感到高兴/自豪。努力去做吧。我永远支持你。
Congratulations on getting your dream job. I feel happy/proud for you. Go for it. I will always support you.

---

I guess your spouse may have obtained a position (职位) / job (工作) as a crew member (机组成员), such as

- pilot 机长)
- co-pilot (副驾驶)
- cabin manager / flight purser 客舱经理 / 乘务长
- flight attendant 空中乘务员 (空乘 / 乘务员)

> 加油！自由飞翔！我们在这里为您服务，始终支持您并欢迎您回家！

It's grammatically correct, but people don't normally say that.
我们在这里为您服务 is equivalent to "we're here to help" which is used in customer service rather than family.
始终支持您 also sounds like an expression in customers service.
您 is used in clerk to supervisor, store to customer, student to teacher. No need to 您 between spouse. For other situations in the family, it depends on their family consensus/tacit understanding.

You can say:

> 恭喜你被录用！太好了，你的梦想成真了（your dream comes true）。我期待看到你在蓝天翱翔（áoxiáng）的样子。

Comment: Thank you! that is very helpful. What is the difference for the usage of 恭喜 and 祝贺? I know 恭喜 is used often in New Years' wishes. Does 祝贺 usage have any relevant context, for example, used more in intimate relationships?

Comment: Also, they did not get a flight-related job, it is a management consulting position which was very difficult to obtain at the #1 firm in the world. Very proud. :)

Comment: @DJG2021 In most cases, you can use these two words interchangeably. On diplomatic and business occasions, 祝贺 is generally said. e.g., 祝贺康明斯中国 2020 年发动机销量突破 67 万台。Congratulations to Cummins China for engine sales exceeding 670 thousand units.